# How to remove fake daughter profile from facebook without an ID?

Tags: facebook, privacy

Some kid at my daughter's school created a fake profile of her (she is 11) but the "report impostor account" page in Facebook requires an ID with a photo, which she doesn't have yet.

I am contacting the kid's parents directly but I would also like to be able to do that using Facebook's processes to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to hear that - if you cannot use the method for verifying by ID, then you might want to try reporting the profile as underage (even if it is fake)

As the parent of child in the profile content, you (hopefully) should be able to get it removed.

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=210036389087590

> If you're reporting a child's account registered under a false date of
>   birth, and the child’s age is reasonably verifiable as under 13, we
>   will promptly delete the account. You will not receive confirmation of
>   this action, but you should no longer be able to view this child’s
>   timeline on the site.
>
> If the reported child’s age is not reasonably verifiable as under 13,
>   then we may not be able to take action on the account. In this case,
>   if you are not the parent of this child, then we strongly recommend
>   that you encourage a parent to contact us personally, using this form.

Comment: This would seem to be the simplest and most direct way of getting the account removed.

Comment: Thank you! I also reported the kid that did that (he is also 11) and hopefully we'll see some online justice and lessons learned.